# What do you call your father's other wife?

Tags: kinship-terms

This is a question for a fanfic of mine, where the main character's father has two wives, the main character's mother and another female. What would the main character call the other wife?

Note: They are dogs, just to put it there. It's a Ginga series fanfic.

~ Louise

Comment: In the Sanskrit epic Ramayana, Rama terms Kaikeyi his "younger mother" in a similar situation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaikeyi for this and more.

Comment: Stepmother, perhaps?

Comment: My “other” mom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use the word **stepmother** here. But if they're not married, you could call the other woman his "girlfriend".

If you want to be dramatic, then you could call her an "impostor". If you want to be salacious, you could call her a "mistress".